# Java Remove duplicates from an arraylist of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to remove duplicated values between arrays and not in themselves

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] s1 = new int[3];
    int[] s2 = new int[3];
    int[] s3 = new int[3];

    ArrayList<int[]> list1 = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    s1[0] = 1;
    s1[1] = 2;
    s1[2] = 3;
    s2[0] = 2;
    s2[1] = 3;
    s2[2] = 4;
    s3[0] = 5;
    s3[1] = 3;
    s3[2] = 6;
    list1.add(s1);
    list1.add(s2);
    list1.add(s3);
    //Set<int[]> hs = new HashSet<int[]>();
    list1 = new ArrayList<int[]>(new LinkedHashSet<int[]>(list1));

    // TODO code application logic here
    for (int[] strArr : list1) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
    }
}
```

In this case the output gave me this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[5, 3, 6]
```

but i want this:

```
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 4]
[5, 0, 6]
```

Yet I couldnt find anything about this so....

Comment: so... you didn't even try anything and expected that we'd just write you the code? I wish there were a limit of 100 points for posting questions.

Comment: // TODO code application logic here <-- what's this for? where is your logic. I agree with @Kayaman.

Comment: Youu should maybe read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: I have put working code as an answer on how to achieve it but in future please post what you have tried in your question. Also please remember to accept it as an answer using the tick next to the answer if you feel it is sufficient :) Refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when writing your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to achieve what you are after is

```
import java.util.*;

public class Array
{
    int[] s1 = {1,2,3};
    int[] s2 = {2,3,4};
    int[] s3 = {5,3,6};
    int[] oS1 = {1,2,3};
    int[] oS2 = {2,3,4};
    int[] oS3 = {5,3,6};

    ArrayList<int[]> list1 = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    ArrayList<int[]> list2 = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    public void compareEditArrays(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c, int[] d)
    {
        HashSet<Integer> map = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i : a)
        {
            map.add(i);
        }

        for (int i : b) 
        {
            if (map.contains(i))
            {
                map.remove(i);
            } 
        }

        for (int i : c) 
        {
            if (map.contains(i))
            {
                map.remove(i);
            } 
        }

        arrayWipe(d);

        int x = 0;
        for(int t:map)
        {
            int tempInt = 0;
            int dd=0;

            for(int i:a)
            {
                if(a[dd]==t)
                {
                    tempInt = dd;
                }
                dd++;
            }

            d[tempInt] = t;
            x++;
        }
    }

    public void runCompareEdit()
    {
        compareEditArrays(oS1,oS2,oS3,s1);
        compareEditArrays(oS2,oS1,oS3,s2);
        compareEditArrays(oS3,oS1,oS2,s3);
    }

    public void arrayWipe(int[] a)
    {
        int x=0;
        for(int t:a)
        {
            a[x] = 0;
            x++;
        }
    }

    public void addDisplayFinalArrays()
    {
        System.out.println("Comparing");
        System.out.println("Old");
        list2.add(oS1);
        list2.add(oS2);
        list2.add(oS3);

        for (int[] strArr : list2) 
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("New");
        list1.add(s1);
        list1.add(s2);
        list1.add(s3);

        for (int[] strArr : list1) 
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Array a = new Array();
        a.runCompareEdit();
        a.addDisplayFinalArrays();
    }
}
```

The code is a bit messy but I have tested it and it works